# Illegal State Exception AsyncTask MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I have two AsyncTask that are updating a mediaplayer and seekbar. The first one is calling runOnUIThread. When I call the second asynctask to update the mediaplayer, I get and IllegalStateException. The log is below. How do I fix this?

```
07-02 08:15:13.786  18990-18990/horatiothomas.com.spotify E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:976)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:929)
            at horatiothomas.com.spotify.ui.TrackPlayerActivityFragment$SwitchTrackPlayerTask$1.success(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.java:260)
            at horatiothomas.com.spotify.ui.TrackPlayerActivityFragment$SwitchTrackPlayerTask$1.success(TrackPlayerActivityFragment.java:238)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This error occurs at the first play or second? If second you need to call reset() after completion.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. If you have any problems with MediaPlayer in the future you can check this page. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States

Comment: That is a really cool resource thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to call reset() on my mediaplayer.

Answer (score 0):

Media Player is not prepared yet or it is still null and you are trying to play with it.